# SharedLib dependency @ Mixed mode APK

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

1. I am building a mixed mode Android project, the project is using the native ffmpeg
2. The Libs are 
   2.1. libavutil.so -> libavutil.so.51 
   2.2. libavcodec.so -> libavcodec.so.54 
   2.3. libavformat.so -> libavformat.so.54
3. My Java code include the following JNI section to load the native libs:
   static {
        System.loadLibrary("avutil");
        System.loadLibrary("avcodec");
        System.loadLibrary("avformat");
   }
4. 'libavcodec.so' depends on 'libavutil.so.51' **AND NOT on 'libavutil.so'.**
5. When running my activity  *System.loadLibrary("avcodec");* excepts with *"could not load needed library 'libavutil.so.51' for 'libavcodec.so' (Library 'libavutil.so.51' not found)"*
6. On my Android.mk I have the following section to have the native libs added to the APK:

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_MODULE := mylib
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../mylib/libmylib.so
   include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
7. replacing libmylib.so with libmylib.so.%some number% cause the build to fail with [LOCAL_SRC_FILES should point to a file ending with ".so"]


   Having the above in mind, how can I have libavcodec loading w/o the dependency problem ?

   - Can I fix libavcodec.so dependency to point to libavutil.so and not to libavutil.so.51 ?
   - Can I change Android.mk so it will be able to pack libavutil.so.51 ( non .SO extention ) ? will it then be loadable using 'System.loadLibrary' ?.

     **Any help will be appreciated!!!**

     Nadav at Sophin

Answer (score 0):

Work-around was simply to use the static libs rather than the dynamic libs, this however, is a temporary work-around as due to LGPL limitations the SharedLibs are mandatory for commercial use.

Comment: Ever find a real solution to this?  I'm in the same hole and face the same limitation due to LGPL.

Comment: Okay, I did finally find a solution to this by changing the Makefile in ffmpeg's distro to generate libraries without the version suffix.  So I have true libavutil.so, libavcodec.so, libswscale.so and all is working on my nexus 4!

Comment: Hi buy, I am facing same problem when I used latest FFMPEG, your point is very useful, but I have not done due to I don't know how to change, can you help me to point out how to change it?